# I'm trying print an array in reverse order but it won't

Tags: javascript, arrays, traversal

I have created an array and I'm trying to print the reverse of it. the output should be 4 3 2 1, but instead, the output I get is undefined 4 3 2 1

Where did this undefined come from?

Can you help to find the logical error here, thanks?

```
"use strict";

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: there is a native method to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Comment: I was expecting the function to print the array in reverse order. this is what the o/p was:  undefined
4
3
2

Comment: Start at `array.length - 1` - array indexes start at zero. and iterate while `i >= 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like  this

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4]

function reverseArray(array1){
  var tmpArray = []
  for(var i=array1.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    tmpArray.push(array1[i]);
  }
  return tmpArray;
}

var reverseArray = reverseArray(array);
console.log(reverseArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because arrays starts at index 0

So you should iter on index  0

```
 for (i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Note also that your code print the reverse of the array it does not reverse it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that use

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var reverseArray = function (array1 = [],) {

    for (i = array1.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
        console.log(array1[i]);
    }

}

reverseArray(array);
```

remember the last index is 3 not 4 so you subtract 1 from it.